# how to make jump page search engine friendly

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I have links on page that scroll page to other parts of the page. Is there a way to make the page search engine friendly.

So lets say if my FAQ page has 2 questions and other content. 1) how to do A? and 2) how to do B?

Someone searches for how to do B? My site shows up with that question as search description's title and when user clicks it jumps to that part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping into different parts of a page are accomplished via anchor tags (#). The problem you'll face is that search engines ignore anchor tags (#). If you don't want to create separate pages, you can:

1. Create a single page with a table of contents at the top to jump users down into their relevant sections (the page title won't be affected but this does most of what you requested).
2. Create a single page with 2 different URLs.  This can be as easy as adding a query parameter on the end of your URL, eg: www.yourwebsite.com/yourcontent and www.yourwebsite.com/yourcontent?param=1.  If your page is created dynamically then you can (on the server side) update your page title and description based on the query parameter as well.

Comment: thanks for taking time for me...can you explain more about 2. Like what does this achieve and how. Two different urls mean two different pages to search engine..so you are saying that have server create dynamically many versions of the main page based on url.

Comment: expanding on this idea: have server dynamically load child page configuring it according to url and expected content. And then instead of sending the rest of page with it have ajax load the parent page. saving some server time...or the way you suggested is good too...use templating. And then scroll to whatever part it needs to be at.

Comment: If you have a dynamic page your server can customize your title/description based on the query string (or anything really).  If you use query parameters though, to google it will look like multiple pages but on your end you are just maintaining a single page.

Comment: Also you don't need to use parent/child pages or ajax to customize your page contents, but you would need to write some code that gets executed on the server, the server then processes the code before it returns the results to the browser.  Another thing to keep in mind is that search engines won't run ajax/javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want parts of a page to have "different titles" then you have to make multiple pages with different URLs and titles in the meta information.  Also remember canonical references to the main page.

So you would have one page for the FAQ with the questions and answers.

One page for question 1 with the question and answer.

Another page for question 2 with question and answer.

Stackoverflow is very good at this.  Note the URL of this question for example.  It has the question in the URL of this page.  This makes that question "search engine friendly".

I suggest you do the same.

You can read on google's webmaster pages about how to set up cononical URLs.  Google (and other search engines) like when you do this.

Comment: so you can't have user jump straight to part of the page from google and not also have google show something different

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - as far as I know, google and other search engines will only show what is on the page.

Comment: but can you configure your page as such that based on search query different parts are focused of what's on the page.